# Connect to SQL Server with trusted connection from linux box

Tags: sql-server

How can I connect to SQL Server with trusted connection from linux box?

I can login linux server using LDAP user name and password. But I got below error when I tried to run sqlcmd.

```
sqlcmd -E -S [ServerName]
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Cannot generate SSPI context.
```

Comment: Is the SQL Server hosted on Linux? If so, you need to configure SQL Server to use LDAP. If it's Windows, you need to configure your Linux Environment to use Kerboros. Neither are simple tasks

Comment: [Tutorial: Use Active Directory authentication with SQL Server on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: The SQL server is hosted on Windows. The below link is for SQL Server hosted on Linux. Do you have instruction to setup Kerboros on Linux?

Comment: The relevant steps are still there, @Welly: [Join SQL Server on a Linux host to an Active Directory domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-join-domain?view=sql-server-ver15). If you want a more expansive answer, SO it the wrong place. you need [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se].